# data-id always returns the same value

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am calling an `api` using `ajax` which returns me a list of available coaches in a particular area. I am then displaying each coach and his details(firstname, picture, email etc) in a `div` using `foreach` loop. Each `div` has a contact button which should send an email to the coach so in order to get the coach email, I have put a hidden `span` element in each coach details and assigned it the value of coach email. Now, when I try to get the value of that span, I always get the value of first coach in the list.
My `HTML` code for displaying the coaches:

```
<!-- Single Coach Item -->
    <li class="product">
        <div class="post_item_wrap">
            <div class="post_featured">
                <div class="post_thumb">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="<?php echo './api/' . $coach["profile_picture"]; ?>" id="coach_image" alt="image" class="coach_img" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="post_content">
                <!-- Hidden field below -->
                <span data-id="<?php echo $coach["email_address"]; ?>" class="hidden_fields coach_email"></span>


                <!-- Name and Bio -->
                <h3 class="coach_name"><?php echo $coach["first_name"] . " " . $coach["last_name"]; ?></h3>
                <span class="price description">
                    <span class="description"><?php echo $coach["coach_bio"]; ?></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Button which triggers the `click` event:

```
<span class="sc_button sc_button_square sc_button_style_2 sc_button_size_small contact_btn">
    <span class="cube flip-to-top">
        <span class="default-state sc_button_iconed none">
            <span>Contact Me</span>
        </span>
        <span class="active-state sc_button_iconed none">
            <span>Contact Me</span>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

And this is how I am trying to get the coach email on `button` click:

```
$(".contact_btn").click(function(e){
    var coach_email=$(".coach_email").data("id");  
    console.log(coach_email);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the button has a common parent with your hidden field you can use `closest` to get this common parent and `find` to go down to your hidden field. For example if your button and your hidden field are in the same div with the class "product_div' :

```
$(".contact_btn").click(function(e){
    var coach_email=$(this).closest('.product_div').find('.coach_email').attr('data-id');  
    console.log(coach_email);
});
```

Comment: it worked, thanks. Just another quick question. I am working on a localhost for now but when I make the api calls, I can see everything(api name, complete api url, params which I passed etc) in the network tab of the inspector so is it good because it made me thinking why this information is openly available in the network tab. I also need to update email and password in my website so this might be some kind of security loop hole. Am I right or it's just normal?

Comment: yes, it's normal. I guess you have a jwt token to call your api, so your api will be able to check who is calling and do or not stuff.
instead of using your browser console, you should take a look on NGROK: https://ngrok.com/
it'll be easier for you